# Limitation of processor resource utilization for specific user

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

Is that possible that for one single user, I will limit somehow procesor resources that can be utilized? For a single query, I can use something like:

```
Option (MAXDOP 4)
```

Is that possible to limit similar way all queries that were executed by a specific user? Of course, if the user will run 10 separate queries I would like not only they will be limited but a limit will be set for cumulative overload.

Comment: If you used dynamic SQL, captured the user, and then added that in the dynamic SQL for that user, you can do it that way.  There may be other ways.  Not sure why you would want to/need to?

Comment: to prevent an by accident one user will kill server

Comment: Have you looked at resource governor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if [SQL Server Resource Governor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor?view=sql-server-ver16) is what you need.

> SQL Server Resource Governor is a feature that you can use to manage SQL Server workload and system resource consumption. Resource Governor enables you to specify limits on the amount of CPU, physical I/O, and memory that incoming application requests can use.

I don't know if you can limit per-user, but you can set workload groups and assign users to one.

Comment: In re: "can limit per user", you can. In the RG classifier function (which runs at log in time) check their login name and assign to whichever workload group you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the "**Enterprise Edition**" of SQL Server, then you can limit the server resources by few steps:

1- Create [Resource Governor Resource Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor-resource-pool?view=sql-server-ver16):

> A resource pool, or pool, represents the physical resources of the
> server. You can think of a pool as a virtual SQL Server instance
> inside of a SQL Server instance.

1.1- Create limited resource pool: the resources are limited in this pool

```
CREATE RESOURCE POOL LimitedResourcePool
WITH
(MIN_CPU_PERCENT=0,
MAX_CPU_PERCENT=25,
MIN_MEMORY_PERCENT=0,
MAX_MEMORY_PERCENT=25)
GO
```

1.2- Create unlimited resource pool: the resources are unlimited in this pool

```
CREATE RESOURCE POOL UnlimitedResourcePool
WITH
(MIN_CPU_PERCENT=25,
MAX_CPU_PERCENT=100,
MIN_MEMORY_PERCENT=25,
MAX_MEMORY_PERCENT=100)
GO
```

2- Create [Resource Governor Workload Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor-workload-group?view=sql-server-ver16):

> A workload group serves as a container for session requests that are
> similar according to the classification criteria that are applied to
> each request.

2.1- Create Workload Group in the `LimitedResourcePool`:

```
CREATE WORKLOAD GROUP LimitedResourceGroup
USING LimitedResourcePool;
GO
```

2.2- Create Workload Group in the `UnlimitedResourcePool`:

```
CREATE WORKLOAD GROUP UnimitedResourceGroup
USING UnlimitedResourcePool;
GO
```

3 - Creating [Resource Governor Classifier Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor-classifier-function?view=sql-server-ver16):

> The SQL Server resource governor classification process assigns
> incoming sessions to a workload group based on the characteristics of
> the session.
>
> Resource Governor supports the classification of incoming sessions.
> Classification is based on a set of user-written criteria contained in
> a function. The results of the function logic enable Resource Governor
> to classify sessions into existing workload groups.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UDFClassifier()
RETURNS SYSNAME
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @WorkloadGroup AS SYSNAME
IF(SUSER_NAME() = 'LimitedUser') 
SET @WorkloadGroup = 'LimitedResourceGroup'
ELSE IF (SUSER_NAME() = 'UnlimitedUser')
SET @WorkloadGroup = 'UnlimitedResourceGroup'
ELSE
SET @WorkloadGroup = 'default'
RETURN @WorkloadGroup
END
GO
-- If the user is within a specific domain, please ensure to provide the username as follows: <DomainName>\<UserName>.
```

4- [Enable Resource Governor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/enable-resource-governor?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR
WITH (CLASSIFIER_FUNCTION=dbo.UDFClassifier);
GO
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE
GO
```

---

> If you want later to [**Disable** Resource Governor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/disable-resource-governor?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR DISABLE;
GO
```

---

> If you want to undo the previous 4 steps:

```
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR WITH (CLASSIFIER_FUNCTION = NULL)
GO
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR DISABLE
GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.UDFClassifier
GO
DROP WORKLOAD GROUP LimitedResourceGroup
GO
DROP WORKLOAD GROUP UnlimitedResourceGroup
GO
DROP RESOURCE POOL LimitedResourcePool
GO
DROP RESOURCE POOL UnlimitedResourcePool
GO
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE
GO
```